# Функциональное программирование Python

Tags: python

Условия задания:

"Информация о студентах хранится в .txt файле. Сформировать набор структур для хранения и обработки информации. Вывести студентов, которые имеют более двух задолженностей в порядке уменьшения их задолженностей. В случае равности некоторых из элементов - осуществить вывод студентов с равным кол-вом задолженностей по среднему баллу(*От автора вопроса: тут тоже имеется ввиду "вывод от большего к меньшему"*). В случае равности баллов - по номеру группы."

Мой код:

```
# DATA CONSTRUCTIONS ( MUST BE REWORKED )

DataArray = []
DeptsArray = [] # COUNT OF DEPTS FOR EVERY PERSON
NamesArray = [] # PPL NAMES
AVGDeptsScore = [] # AVG SCORE
GroupsNumbers = []
ListOfIndexes = []
outsideCounter = 0
saver = 0

# READ DATA FROM FILE

with open("Data.txt") as file:
    DataArray = file.read().splitlines()

# ANONYMOUS FUNCTIONS BLOCK ( MANDATORY REQUIRMENT )

sliceDepts = lambda : list(map(int, DataArray[7::9]))
sliceNames = lambda : list(map(str, DataArray[0::9]))
sliceAVGDepts = lambda : list(map(int, DataArray[8::9]))
sliceGroupNumber = lambda : list(map(int, DataArray[1::9]))

# INFORMATION SLICES

DeptsArray = sliceDepts()
NamesArray = sliceNames()
AVGDeptsScore = sliceAVGDepts()
GroupsNumbers = sliceGroupNumber()

def bubbleSort(number): # RECURSIVE BUBBLE SORT
    global outsideCounter
    global DeptsArray
    if(outsideCounter != len(DeptsArray) - 1):
        if(number != len(DeptsArray) - outsideCounter - 1):
            if(DeptsArray[number] < DeptsArray[number + 1]):
                synchronization(number, number + 1)
                _tmp = DeptsArray[number + 1]
                DeptsArray[number + 1] = DeptsArray[number]
                DeptsArray[number] = _tmp
                return bubbleSort(number + 1)
            return bubbleSort(number + 1)
        outsideCounter += 1
        return bubbleSort(0)

def synchronization(bun1, bun2): # bun1, bun2 - local integer positions for lists elements

    # NAMES SYNCHRONIZATION
    _tmpName = NamesArray[bun2]
    NamesArray[bun2] = NamesArray[bun1]
    NamesArray[bun1] = _tmpName

    # AVG DEPTS SCCORE SYNCHRONIZATION
    _tmpAVG = AVGDeptsScore[bun2]
    AVGDeptsScore[bun2] = AVGDeptsScore[bun1]
    AVGDeptsScore[bun1] = _tmpAVG

def checkDuplicates(cnt): # cnt - local iterator
    if(cnt != len(DeptsArray) - 1):
        if(DeptsArray[cnt] == DeptsArray[cnt + 1] or DeptsArray[cnt] == DeptsArray[cnt - 1]):
            ListOfIndexes.append(cnt)
            ListOfIndexes.append(DeptsArray[cnt])
            return checkDuplicates(cnt + 1)
        if(DeptsArray[cnt] != DeptsArray[cnt + 1] and (DeptsArray[cnt - 1] not in ListOfIndexes) or DeptsArray[cnt] != DeptsArray[cnt + 1] and (DeptsArray[cnt] not in ListOfIndexes)):
            if(DeptsArray[cnt] >= 2):
                print(str(DeptsArray[cnt]) + " " + NamesArray[cnt] + " " + str(AVGDeptsScore[cnt]))
        return checkDuplicates(cnt + 1)

# CODE START

print(DeptsArray) # OUTPUT [2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1]
bubbleSort(0)
DeptsArray.append(-1) # ADDING LIMITER
checkDuplicates(0)
print(ListOfIndexes)
```

Вся сложность заключается в том, что это мой первый опыт в "функционалке", если можно сказать так.

Переработанный код для запуска на Вашем компьютере(*вырезан файловый ввод, данные готовы сразу*):

```
# DATA CONSTRUCTIONS ( MUST BE REWORKED )

DeptsArray = [2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1]
NamesArray = ['Petrov Petr Petrov', 'Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich', 'Prokopenko Katerina Sergeevna', 'Slavyanova Slavyana Vyacheslavovna', 'Shymko Dmitriy Igorevich', 'Delf John', 'Sun Ci']
AVGDeptsScore = [19, 30, 50, 50, 45, 0, 59]
GroupsNumbers = [123, 123, 450, 200, 300, 690, 690]
ListOfIndexes = []
outsideCounter = 0
saver = 0

def bubbleSort(number): # RECURSIVE BUBBLE SORT
    global outsideCounter
    global DeptsArray
    if(outsideCounter != len(DeptsArray) - 1):
        if(number != len(DeptsArray) - outsideCounter - 1):
            if(DeptsArray[number] < DeptsArray[number + 1]):
                synchronization(number, number + 1)
                _tmp = DeptsArray[number + 1]
                DeptsArray[number + 1] = DeptsArray[number]
                DeptsArray[number] = _tmp
                return bubbleSort(number + 1)
            return bubbleSort(number + 1)
        outsideCounter += 1
        return bubbleSort(0)

def synchronization(bun1, bun2): # bun1, bun2 - local integer positions for lists elements

    # NAMES SYNCHRONIZATION
    _tmpName = NamesArray[bun2]
    NamesArray[bun2] = NamesArray[bun1]
    NamesArray[bun1] = _tmpName

    # AVG DEPTS SCCORE SYNCHRONIZATION
    _tmpAVG = AVGDeptsScore[bun2]
    AVGDeptsScore[bun2] = AVGDeptsScore[bun1]
    AVGDeptsScore[bun1] = _tmpAVG

def checkDuplicates(cnt): # cnt - local iterator
    if(cnt != len(DeptsArray) - 1):
        if(DeptsArray[cnt] == DeptsArray[cnt + 1] or DeptsArray[cnt] == DeptsArray[cnt - 1]):
            ListOfIndexes.append(cnt)
            ListOfIndexes.append(DeptsArray[cnt])
            return checkDuplicates(cnt + 1)
        if(DeptsArray[cnt] != DeptsArray[cnt + 1] and (DeptsArray[cnt - 1] not in ListOfIndexes) or DeptsArray[cnt] != DeptsArray[cnt + 1] and (DeptsArray[cnt] not in ListOfIndexes)):
            if(DeptsArray[cnt] >= 2):
                print(str(DeptsArray[cnt]) + " " + NamesArray[cnt] + " " + str(AVGDeptsScore[cnt]))
        return checkDuplicates(cnt + 1)

# CODE START

bubbleSort(0)
DeptsArray.append(-1)
```

Проще говоря, визуальный максимум которого я добился: вывод первого уникального студента с четырьмя задолженностями и отсортированные данные во всех листах.

К сожалению, ума не приложу каким образом осуществить вывод повторяющихся студентов по баллам используя функциональное программирование, потому надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Если вопрос и не будет закрыт, то попрошу более уважаемых юзеров не удалять его, дабы такие же новички как и я могли забрать из моего кода нужные части, к примеру рекурсивную пузырьковую сортировку или иные фичи :)

Comment: Классы то можно использовать? Сделайте классы вместо отдельных массивов с данными, которые вы вяжете и "синхронизируете" вручную. И тогда всё будет гораздо проще делать.